# Android Customizable Expandable List View Item

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, listitem

My problem is simple: I need to make a layout similar to android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 which can fit more than one textview in the layout, as well as show the little '>' symbol that indicates that the tab is expandable.

How can this best be accomplished? My first thought was to use the layout as a background of a linear layout with two textviews in it, but I can't seem to make that work.

Comment: Downvoted already? Was my question not specific enough, or did I do something wrong? I'd like to improve my question, so please leave a comment indicating what exactly warranted the downvote, that way I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) has a pretty good tutorial on how to achieve custom list views through Adapters.

Basically, what you do is you create a Layout with the looks you want for the list items and then you extend an adapter (ArrayAdapter for instance), see section 4. Then, in your activity, you create an instance of your Adapter implementation and populate it from an Array containing the data for the list.

Also have a look at the [Developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for how to make the list scroll smoothly with the ViewHolder pattern.

And if you feel you need more info on the expandable part maybe [the hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) can help.